# Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.0-rc.1.20451.13 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0) / win7-x86

Tags: entity-framework-core, nuget, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to update my packages but I got some errors like this:

**The error is:**

> Error NU1202   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
> 5.0.0-rc.1.20451.13 is not compatible with net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0) / win7-x86.  Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0.0-rc.1.20451.13 supports:
> netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)    API
> E:...\API\API.csproj 1

**API.csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CloudinaryDotNet" Version="1.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20414.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.0-preview8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.7.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image: nuget package manager]

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --info .NET SDK (reflecting any
> global.json):
> Version:   5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10
> Commit:    473d1b592e
>
> Runtime Environment:
> OS Name:     Windows
> OS Version:  10.0.17763
> OS Platform: Windows
> RID:         win10-x64
> Base Path:   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10\

[image: command line]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your csproj file shows references to EF Core 5 Preview 8 packages, not RC1. You have to upgrade all of those packages

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio v16.8-preview-3.2 and then the project is rebuilt correctly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue:

I updated my Visual Studio program from version **16.7** to **16.8** and now, problem solved!

**I checked update manually**

*This solution is written in the comments of this question but I wanted to make it an answer to help others like me*

Answer (score 16):

You have to upgrade your nuget installer to latest version.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite/

https://www.nuget.org/downloads

If you are using Azure Devops, you can add a task step into your pipeline.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: 5.0.x

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      inputs:
        versionSpec: ''
        checkLatest: true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, updating the nuget worked for me.

Comment: tysm for the yaml snip!!

Answer (score 4):

To develop any ASP.NET Core 5.0 app, you need Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 or later, with the ASP.NET and web development workload installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/create-project

Answer (score 0):

I had a global.json file in my project. After removing it problem was fixed because it mentioned a .net core 3.1 sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Open .csproj file in notepad and change the target version from 3.1 to 2.1
From

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard5.0</TargetFramework>
```

To

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
```

Save file and close. Clean Solution then rebuild the solution.